# Facebook Android SDK 3.8 : Publish open graph story

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am having a few problems with publishing a new Open Graph story in Facebook SDK 3.8. I have a story of this form :

Rate a Movie

This is how my code looks :

```
OpenGraphObject object = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("app_name:movie");
object.setProperty("title", "GadFather - Test"); 
object.setProperty("image", "http://www.example.com/image.jpg");
object.setProperty("url", "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/");
object.setProperty("description", "Test.. ");

OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
action.setProperty("previewPropertyName", object);

FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "rate.movie").build();
```

I get this error :

04-30 23:49:43.594: E/ACRA(2161): com.app_name fatal error : A property named "rate.movie" was not found on the action.  The name of the preview property must match the name of an action property.

Is there anything I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that I can see that you are doing incorrectly.

The first is that the 3rd parameter to OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder should be the name of the preview property.  This is probably like "movie" or whatever the object of the "rate.movie" action is.  You should not set it explicitly on the action like you have done.

The second is that when you create your action, you need to also set a type on it.  You can do this explicitly by calling

```
action.setType("rate.movie");
```

or by using the builtin helper

```
OpenGraphAction.Factory.createForPost()
```

which takes as an argument the type of the action.

Then lastly, you need to set the property on the action for the object like

```
action.setProperty("movie", object);
```

Hope these tips help clear it up for you :)